# Check whether current time is in range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Googlesheets and can't find a way to check if current time is within 2 time values (e.g. 08:00 and 16:00).

Boolean check is straightforward:
`=AND(NOW()>=A2,NOW()<=B2)`

If current time is 16:00, desired output:

```
Start   End    Check  
8:00    18:00  TRUE
8:00    13:00  FALSE
```

However, I'm just getting FALSE returns constantly:

```
Start   End    Check  
8:00    18:00  FALSE
8:00    13:00  FALSE
```

Issue seems to lie with the NOW() function. If I replace NOW() with static time values, the formula works.

Is there any way to call the current time without using NOW()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### Use [`=TIMEVALUE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en)

Sample:

`=AND(TIMEVALUE(NOW())>=TIMEVALUE(A2),TIMEVALUE(NOW())<=TIMEVALUE(B2))`

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Exactly what I needed.